# How to stop refreshing viewpager content?

Tags: android, listview

I have 3 page in viewpager, each page have ListView . Data of ListView is supply from database.When I move from last to fist page data of listview load again from data it take more time. Look disgusting 
Please Solve my problem..

```
   package searchFragments;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import com.example.newdictionary.R;

import database.DBHelper;

public class SimilerWordFragment extends Fragment {
    SimpleAdapter adapter;
    ListView listView;
    List<HashMap<String, String>> map;
    String[] from = { "ENGLISH", "HINDI", "TYPE" };
    String word;
    ProgressBar bar;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.similer_word_fragment, container,
                false);
        bar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.all_progress_bar);
        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.similer_word_list_view);

        int[] to = { R.id.spelling, R.id.meaning, R.id.type };
        map = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), map,
                R.layout.list_view_item, from, to);
        word = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("word");

        new Task().execute();

        return v;
    }

    class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();
            bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            DBHelper db = new DBHelper(getActivity());
            Cursor c = db.getSuggestion(word);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    HashMap<String, String> h = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    h.put(from[0], c.getString(0));
                    h.put(from[1], c.getString(1));
                    h.put(from[2], c.getString(2));
                    map.add(h);

                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3); where pager is your ViewPager.

Comment: I have same problem with drawer layout